# Conditional formatting with values in comma in same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

[image]

Hello Everyone,
In above table i want to color columns B,C,D,E,F in green if respective months contains in column A for that particular row. If you know other way apart from conditional formatting, please explain. Thanks

I tried with conditional formatting but because of comma in column A, i am not getting required output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDIT

I realized using `SEARCH()` function could be most easiest way hence sharing it,

[image]

---

• Follow the steps accordingly to conditionally format the cells:

• Select the range from `B2:F4`

• From `Home Tab` --> Under `Styles Group` --> Click On `Conditional Formatting` --> Click `New` or short cut to open is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

• From `New Formatting Rule` Dialogue Box --> Click on the **Last Rule** --> Use a formula to determine which cells to format

• Enter the formula in the `Edit the Rule Description`

```
=SEARCH(B$1,$A2)
```

• Click on --> `Format` --> Choose your desired fill color from the `Fill` tab

• Click `Ok` --> `Ok` Done!!!

---

Well, you can use **either** of these methods, to accomplish the desired output.

[image]

---

• Follow the steps accordingly to conditionally format the cells:

• Select the range from `B2:F4`

• From `Home Tab` --> Under `Styles Group` --> Click On `Conditional Formatting` --> Click `New` or short cut to open is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

• From `New Formatting Rule` Dialogue Box --> Click on the **Last Rule** --> Use a formula to determine which cells to format

• Enter the formula in the `Edit the Rule Description`

```
=XMATCH(B$1,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT($A2,",",CHAR(10)),1))
```

• Click on --> `Format` --> Choose your desired fill color from the `Fill` tab

• Click `Ok` --> `Ok` Done!!!

---

Or, you can use the following formula as well, instead of the above --> Applies to range `=$B$7:$F$9`

[image]

---

```
=SUM(N(TOROW(TEXTSPLIT($A2,",",CHAR(10),1),3)=B$6))
```

---

**Note:** Change the **ranges** and **cell references** as per your suit, also I have assumed you are in **MS365** and one more importantly I have assumed you have **line breaks as delimiter other than commas.**

---

**Edit:**

To return the number as `1` simply use the following formula in cells `B2:F4`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$1,$A2)))
```

And Fill Right & Fill Down!

Comment: @Pramod please refer the answers it has been updated. using the formula `=N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$1,$A2)))` you need to enter in cell `B2` and then fill down and fill right!

Comment: Thanks Brother, sorry for following up multiple times on same question, where condition is not matching it is returning 0, I want to to remove 0 too.

Comment: @Pramod select the range `B2:F4` hit `CTRL 1` --> `Format Cells` Window Opens --> Click on `Number Tab` --> Category `Custom` --> Type --> `General;;`

Comment: Yes, it hides the `0`s note that. If you want to specifically remove the `0`s and show as blank you could use `=LET(x,N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$1,$A2))),IF(x=0,"",x))`